# Embed gist tag {% gist 7555c74 %} in github minima not working

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, gist, minima

I am trying to add code excerpts via my gists using tag `{% gist 1234567 %}`. But they are not getting displayed in my post. They are displayed as is. `{% gist 1234567 %}`.

My post is a markdown file which I am hosting using github pages with jekyll minima theme on github. So the link to the posts look like this
`https://github.com/<user>/blog/<postname>.md`

I added the line to include gists into the _config.yml file. Following is the code in the _config.yml file.

```
show_excerpts: true # set to true to show excerpts on the homepage

# Build settings
theme: minima

# generate social links in footer
minima:
  social_links:
    twitter: abcd
    github:  abcd
    linkedin: abcd
  
  skin: solarized-dark

# If you want to link only specific pages in your header, uncomment
# this and add the path to the pages in order as they should show up
header_pages:
- about.md

plugins:
 - jekyll-feed
 - jekyll-seo-tag
 - jekyll-gist
```

I do not see any gemfiles in the folder structure with minima theme.

As a background - I used the simplest method to create the blog. Enabled github pages, chose a theme, customized the site and created / posted the blog posts. I do not even have a local environment.

What else do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the full git commit ID in the tag and my gists were displayed in the markdown file.

{% gist 1234567xxxxxxxxx.... %}

Weird when the 7 characters generally are enough.
But this worked for me.